# CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master' for Azure AppService GitHub Repository

Tags: database, azure, xamarin, github

I am writing a project using `xamarin` forms and I have just started trying to insert data into an Azure database. 
I am following the course on Udemy called The Complete Xamarin Developer Course:

**iOS And Android!**

which has detailed instructions on how to do this however, the app keeps freezing for about 20 seconds and then produces the error

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'

when I try and insert a row.

The error is very strange because I am not creating any tables in my c#, however I believe the problem has something to do with my GitHub account or repository. I have linked it below because there is a line:

```java
mobileApp.tables.add('Accounts'); // Create a table for 'Accounts' with default settings
```

which seems to fit the description of the error. This code is for my `AppService` which is used to connect my mobile app to the database. However I have only edited a tiny bit of this code, pretty much all of it is copied from the Udemy course.

https://github.com/BelleDelphineLover/SwayBowmenBackend

As side note, I had a couple of difficulties getting permission to use the repository for my `AppService` but after going into the GitHub settings, Applications, Authorise OAuth Apps and selecting Azure App Service I managed to fix it, but this could perhaps be the cause.

I'm writing this for my A level coursework so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, `master` is like the default database in SQL Server (which is what Azure uses under the hood).  Basically if you didn't tell your application to use a different database, it would use `master` by default.

Comment: Did you specify the database you want to connect to in  your Azure SQL database connection string?

Comment: @Leon Yue Yes, I have specified the database in the connection string as my course described and checked it for mistakes a dozen times. Here it is: '''Data Source=tcp:swayserver.database.windows.net,1433:Initial Catalog=swayDatabase;User ID=IHJOHNSON@swayserver;Password=***** '''   I am certain the credentials are right because I changed them to test what would happen if they were wrong and I got a different error.